# retrieve rows via join and datetime query where datetime is in past AND NOT in future

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a three table structure as follows (simplified):

```
users
-----
id

purchases
---------
id
user_id

events
------
id
purchase_id
starts_on (datetime)
```

I want to select all users who have an event that took place before some date in the past, but who do NOT have an event in the future.  You can think of this as asking the question, "Which of my users were previously engaged with my company by attending events, but are not any longer?"

This query is being generated in Rails and I have cleaned it up to look as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.id FROM `users` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `events` ON events.user_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchases` ON `purchases`.id = `events`.purchase_id
WHERE events.starts_on <= '2013-07-15' AND NOT events.starts_on >= '2013-08-12'
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Although this query successfully retrieves users who have events prior to the first date parameter, it still includes users who have an event that starts in the future, which is not what I want.  It appears that the "AND NOT" portion of my query is not working as expected.

I initially suspected that the problem was the use of a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN, but changing this made no difference.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a group function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.id FROM `users` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `events` ON events.user_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchases` ON `purchases`.id = `events`.purchase_id
WHERE events.starts_on <= '2013-07-15' or events.starts_on >= '2013-08-12'
group by `users`.id
having min(starts_on) <= '2013-07-15' and max(starts_on) < '2013-08-12'
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond; however, I still get users that are associated with events that take place in the future with this query.

Comment: Could you take a look at the SQL Fiddle and see if the tables are set up correctly - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4369/1

Comment: It seems right, but in my application, although I get fewer results this way, I'm still getting stuff in the future.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I appreciate the effort.  I can't tell if the problem is something weird I'm doing or not.  I'm going to accept your answer in spite of my uncertainty on this, and I'm going to find another way of dealing with it.